# Preload minitest in memory to increase the speed

Tags: ruby, minitest

Good day.

On my PC running pure file with `require 'minitest/autorun'` spends 4 seconds. This makes development process feels slow. Is there a way to run `minitest` in background or load it some how in memory? Some thing like `Spring` in `Rails`.

```
$ time ruby tmp.rb
Run options: --seed 46450

# Running:



Finished in 0.002043s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m3.706s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Tests itself spend 2ms when loading `minitest` use almost 4 seconds. I'm seeking for way how to spend this 4 seconds ones, and then spend time only for tests.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/guard/guard

and

https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest

will change your life...